# angular/ui-mask ip address

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mask

I use angular/ui-mask in my project. Now I need a mask for block ip address range (example 192.168.70.18/20). For example:

```
 <input  ng-model="address" ui-mask="9?9?9.9?9?9.9?9?9.9?9?9/9?9" ui-mask-placeholder-char="_" placeholder="" ng-disabled="disabled">
```

The problem is so I can only enter this IP address: 192.168.125.254

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Sheinar/Lvc0u55v/6133/

Answer (score 0):

I think this solve your problem:

```
$scope.$watch('address', function (address) {
    if (!address || address.length < 15) return;

    var endFrom = parseInt(address.substr(9, 3)),
        endTo = parseInt(address.substr(12, 3));

    if (endFrom > endTo) {
        alert('invalida range');
        $scope.address = address.substr(0, 12);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/matheusdev/Lvc0u55v/6144/

Comment: I still can not insert the dot separator after first or second symbol. I can not enter less than three symbols in the section although I set mask like 9?9?9.

Comment: check out this module (IPv4 example): http://candreoliveira.github.io/bower_components/angular-mask/examples/index.html

Answer (score 0):

First download ngxMaskModule. (npm i ngx-mask).

Import it into the shared module. (NgxMaskModule.forRoo())

On the html side, add mask='IP' to the input text.